# How to add forms to test in angular 5

Tags: testing, angular5

I created an app in angular 5. Now I want to add some tests.

At the moment almost all the specs are failing even though I didnt even add anything.

For my first component it says:
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

How do i inject the necessary dependencys in the component?

Right now I have this:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [{
        provide: Router,
        useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); }
      }, AuthentificationService, NotificationService, FormBuilder]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

This is the constructor of the component:

```
 constructor(private router: Router, private auth: AuthentificationService, private ns: NotificationService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At the moment almost all the specs are failing even though I didnt even add anything.

Seems like you are using something like [this](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) or [this](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form).

> For my first component it says: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

Something like this should take care of this particular error, note the imports-statement after declarations:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule], 
      providers: [{
        provide: Router,
        useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate"); }
      }, AuthentificationService, NotificationService, FormBuilder]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

You'll of course have to add it to the imports at the file level as well but it seems you got those details already.